# How to solve this JVM error in Blackberry simulator?

Tags: blackberry, rim-4.6

I am getting error ("`JVM Error 545 incompatible or corrupt file system`") while building the application in blackberry simulator and I am using the blackberry jde 4.6.

I could not even see the first screen of the simulator.
Can any one tell me what is the reason for this error and how to solve this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This [thread](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/154721-jvm-error-545-8100-simulator.html) suggests to reinstall the JDE or the simulator
- This [one](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/62709-jvm-error-545-bb-simulator.html) suggests:

> in the JDE try "`file -> erase file system and erase non volatile storage`".

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse, Just close the Simulator and press the Clean Simulator option in the Blackberry Menu or there is a button in the toolbar too!!

Comment: Thanks!! I've totally forgot about that menu option, and lately have been purging the sim by hand in console.. let's summarize that as "uurrghh".

Answer (score 2):

If you are running your application on eclipse, browse to `Eclipse_Folder\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.36\components\simulator` and delete all `.debug` files and `.dmp` files.

Restart your eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

for the message "**JVM error 545 invalid or corrupt files**" Delete and Reinstall the Simulator, that will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

delete those files

(.cod) which are created by you & clean.bat ( simulator directory )

& then go to file option ( in simulator ) -> restore to Factory default !